# Union of Two Geometric Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Say $A \sim \operatorname{Geo}(p)$ and $B \sim \operatorname{Geo}(q)$, and $A$ and $B$ are independent.

How would one calculate the probability $k$ for the geometric distribution of A or B? (ie getting a success of either A (prob p) or success with B (prob q)).

Comment: What is meant by "$A$ or $B$"? Union is an operation performed on sets, not functions...

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified. Basically A or B is getting a success with either A (prob p) or success with B (prob q).

Answer (score 2):

$$P(\{A =k \} \cup \{ B = k\})=P(A=k)+P(B=k)-P(\{A=k\}\cap \{B=k\})$$

You might like to use independence to evaluate the last term.